# Why doesn't Android Studio include folders that start with underscores in the APK?

Tags: android, filenames, assets, android-studio-2.3

We are planning on adding Android support for our product. We have a large number of data files that accompany our product which we plan on putting in the assets folder. Many of these folders start with an underscore. When building the APK folders that start with an underscore are excluded from the APK which prevents our app from working as it is missing most of its data. How can I get the build process to include these files? I've done a bunch of searching and haven't found any information about why this is being done.

For example, if I have the following structure in the assets folder:

```
Assets\
    _underscore\
        a_file.txt
        b_file.txt
    noUnderscore\
        _underscore_sub\
            graphic1.png
            graphic2.png
        c_file.txt
        d_file.txt
```

Only the following will be included in the APK:

```
Assets\
    noUnderscore\
        c_file.txt
        d_file.txt
```

We would like to avoid renaming folders if possible as they are generated and changing the way they are generated would require significant code changes and potential bugs.